# Count the number of ways to select a committee of 5 out of 20 with constraint.

Tags: combinatorics, proof-verification

I'm working through Bona's "A Walk Through Combinatorics" and I came across this problem:

> A company has $20$ employees, $12$ male and $8$ female. How many ways are
>   there to form a $5$ person committee that contains at least one male and
>   at least one female?

I realise that this question has been asked here before multiple times and that the standard way to solve such problems is to enumerate all the possible committees and then subtract the ones that do not satisfy the constraint, i.e., consist entirely of the same sex; thus giving the answer: $20C5-12C5-8C5 = 14656$

However, I first tried to solve it like this:
A pair of a man and a woman can be first chosen in $12*8$ ways, thus leaving $3$ open slots on the committee which can be filled in $18C3$ ways; thus giving an answer $12*8*18C3 = 78336$

What is the error in reasoning here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are $\binom{20}5=15504$ ways to make *any* committee from the people available. That the incorrect answer is much larger than this upper limit suggests an error of *overcounting*, which is a common mistake in combinatorial problems.

For this problem, suppose the initial male and female chosen are Andy and Bridget respectively. Then we select two more females and one more male – Cindy, Danielle, Ethan. This counts as one selection.

But we could also select Cindy and Ethan first, then Andy, Bridget and Danielle. This should not be counted as a distinct way, but the incorrect method does this. Hence the error of overcounting.

Comment: Just out of curiosity; is there any way to find the exact number of/compensate for multiple counts done in such a scenario?

Comment: @Akay Divide the selections into 4 males/1 female, 2 males/3 females and so on. Count the number of ways for each case using the incorrect method, then divide by a correction factor: 4 for the 4-of-one-gender/1-of-other cases, 6 in the remaining two cases. This is longer than the canonical solution, but it works.

Comment: Thanks! This really helps me see what exactly I was doing. :)

Answer (score 0):

The error in the other method is double-counting.

For example, the following combinations are essentially identical:

- $M_1+W_1,M_2+M_3+M_4$
- $M_2+W_1,M_1+M_3+M_4$
- $M_3+W_1,M_1+M_2+M_4$
- $M_4+W_1,M_1+M_2+M_3$

Comment: Just out of curiosity; is there any way to find the exact number of/compensate for multiple counts done in such a scenario?

Comment: @Akay: Well, you can simply subtract the correct result from he incorrect result (i.e., $78336-14656$)...